# Is it possible to add a route to the RouteCollection in MVC?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I couldn't think of a reasonable title for this post.

The problem I'm having is that I have an SQL database attached to my MVC website. Within the website I have a news/blog system that I have worked on which stores the data in the database and pulls the information on request.

The problem is the routing. I currently have it set up to pull the information about the routing of each individual page as this:

> var newsr = new NewsResources();
>
> foreach (var item in newsr.GetAllNewsItems())
>   {
>       item.Title = item.Title.Replace(' ', '-').ToLower();
>
> ```
> routes.MapRoute(item.Title, "News/" + item.Title,
> new {controller = "News", action = "Post", id = item.ID});}
> ```

When I add a new news item however, this doesn't go into the routing system which is proving to be a right pain. I've had a google search for dynamically adding url routing but I can't seem to find a solution.

What I want to know is, is it possible to add a page to the routing system via the page controller once I have saved the post into the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think you need to Do a For Each loop across all your POst item and add routes for that. You may do it like this

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
     routes.MapRoute("SingleItem", "News/{title}",
             new { controller = "Items", action = "PostFromTitle" });

     // and the generic route
     routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", 
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", 
                                  id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
        );

}
```

This will route   `../News/SomeTitle` request to your `PostFromTitle` action method of `NewsController`. Read the title there and get the post from there.

```
public ActionResult PostFromTitle(string title)
{
  var post=repo.GetPostFromTitle(title);
  return View("~/Views/News/Post.cshtml",post);
}
```

Comment: Well this is how I wanted to do it. Unfortunately this is a team project, and the other members want the database to reference pages by their int ID rather than a string title.

Comment: @pcjc92 the two options aren't mutually exclusive.  You can still reference the items by id - you're just creating a function to look them up by title to support the URL requirement

Answer (score 0):

It may be better to an action that takes a title as a parameter.

```
routes.MapRoute("NewsItem", "News/{title}", 
    new { controller = "News", action = "ShowNews"  }
```